# using of std::accumulate

Tags: c++, stl

Need prettier solution of below example but with std::accumulate.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
public:
    Object( double a, double b ):
        a_( a ),
        b_( b )
    {}

    double GetA() const { return a_; }
    double GetB() const { return b_; }
    // other methods
private:
    double a_;
    double b_;
};

class Calculator
{
public:
    Calculator( double& result ):
        result_( result )
    {}

    void operator() ( const Object& object )
    {
        // some formula
        result_ += object.GetA() * object.GetB();
    }
private:
    double& result_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< Object > collection;
    collection.push_back( Object( 1, 2 ) );
    collection.push_back( Object( 3, 4 ) );

    double result = 0.0;
    std::for_each( collection.begin(), collection.end(),
                   Calculator( result ) );

    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So why don't you use std::accumulate? What exactly is the question?

Comment: @jalf: Good point -- I'm wondering what is it that my code is missing :)

Comment: Acumulate returns what? I thought it returns the same type as an object, no?

Comment: vector<T>::value_type which in your case will be a double.

Comment: why vector<T>::valie_type is double and not is Object?

Comment: I'm on pot. Accumulate's return type is the same as the init value. Vector<T>::value_type is Object, however.

Comment: That's what I was doubt using accumulate. I thought it won't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

do changes in Calculator and main function.

```
struct Calculator
{
    double operator() ( double result, const Object& obj )
    {
        return result + ( obj.GetA() * obj.GetB());
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::vector< Object > collection;
    collection.push_back( Object( 1, 2 ) );
    collection.push_back( Object( 3, 4 ) );

    double result = std::accumulate( collection.begin(), collection.end(), 0, Calculator() );
    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

also it could be better:

```
double sumABProduct( double result, const Object& obj )
{
    return result + ( obj.GetA() * obj.GetB());
}

double result = std::accumulate( collection.begin(), collection.end(), 0, sumABProduct );
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:** Boost.Lambda makes this a piece of cake:

```
// headers
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>
using namespace boost::lambda;
// ...
cout << accumulate(dv.begin(), dv.end(), 
                   0, 
                   _1 += bind(&strange::value, _2)) //strange defined below
     << endl;
```

**Update:** This has been bugging me for a while. I can't just get any of the STL algorithms to work in a decent manner. So, I rolled my own:

```
// include whatever ...
using namespace std;

// custom accumulator that computes a result of the 
// form: result += object.method();
// all other members same as that of std::accumulate
template <class I, class V, class Fn1, class Fn2>
V accumulate2(I first, I last, V val, Fn1 op, Fn2 memfn) {
    for (; first != last; ++first)
        val = op(val, memfn(*first));
    return val;
}

struct strange {
    strange(int a, int b) : _a(a), _b(b) {}
    int value() { return _a + 10 * _b; }
    int _a, _b;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<strange> dv;
    dv.push_back(strange(1, 3));
    dv.push_back(strange(4, 6));
    dv.push_back(strange(20, -11));        
    cout << accumulate2(dv.begin(), dv.end(), 
                        0, std::plus<int>(), 
                        mem_fun_ref(&strange::value)) << endl;
}
```

Of course, the original solution still holds:
The easiest is to implement an `operator+`. In this case:

```
double operator+(double v, Object const& x) {
        return v + x.a_;
}
```

and make it a friend of `Object` or member (look up why you may prefer one over the other):

```
class Object
{
   //...
  friend double operator+(double v, Object const& x);
```

and you're done with:

```
 result = accumulate(collection.begin(), collection.end(), 0.0);
```

My earlier approach doesn't work because we need a `binary_function`.

[std::accumulate](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html) manual.

Comment: I think the third parameter to accumulate should be 0 not result. result has not yet been defined at that point.

Comment: It shouldn't. 0 is an int. Pass 0.0, which is a double.

Comment: I can't implmenent operator +. Because there will be many others f(object). In one case it just getA()*getB(). In other getC()*getD().

Comment: That leaves you with no other choice but to create a set of custom binary functions to pass to templates. Note, you can make them friends of your Object class.

Answer (score 1):

here is an issue here, I guess the arguments are written in the wrong order should be:

```
result = std::accumulate(collection.begin(), collection.end(), Object(0),Adapt())
where Adapt is defined thus:

struct Adapt { 
    static double mul(Object const &x) { return x.GetA() * x.GetB(); }
    static Object operator()(Object const &x, Object const &y) { 
       return Object(mul(x)+mul(y)) ; } };
```

in this case of accumulate, the result is contained in a returned Object.

If you are using gnu parallel mode the functor will give you problems if the result and the actual object referred to by the iterator are different.

```
struct Adapt { 
        static double mul(Object const &x) { return x.GetA() * x.GetB(); }
        static double operator()(Object const &x, Object const &y) { 
           return mul(x)+mul(y) ; } };
result = std::accumulate(collection.begin(), collection.end(), 0.0,Adapt())
```

will not work with gnu parallel mode for some strange and silly reason.

Answer (score 1):

Using c++0x:

```
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
  public:
     Object( double a, double b ):
        a_( a ),
        b_( b )
      {}

    double GetA() const { return a_; }
    double GetB() const { return b_; }
    // other methods
  private:
    double a_;
    double b_;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< Object > collection;
    collection.push_back( Object( 1, 2 ) );
    collection.push_back( Object( 3, 4 ) );
    double result = std::accumulate( collection.begin(), collection.end(), 0,
                                     [] (double result, const Object& obj) 
                                     {
                                       return result + obj.GetA() * obj.GetB();
                                     }
                                   ); 

   std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One would hope this is homework...

```
struct Adapt { 
    static double mul(Object const &x) { return x.GetA() * x.GetB(); }
    static double operator()(Object const &x, Object const &y) { 
       return mul(x)+mul(y); } };
```

and

```
result = std::accumulate(collection.begin(), collection.end(), Object(0,0),Adapt() );
```

assuming you're not allowed to touch the declaration of Object.

Comment: the result of accumulate should be 'double' and not an 'Adapt'