# Good source for learning how to work with xml in F#

Tags: xml, data-structures, f#

Now that I'm working in F#, is it time to start writing up some custom data structures and parsers? Or is it kosher to continue using the xml technologies provided by .NET?

Comment: Some potentially useful helper functions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833180/handy-f-snippets/3720452#3720452)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nice paper by Don Syme with related example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2007/04/07/draft-paper-on-f-active-patterns.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a good summary document or great example code, but a Bing search for "F# XElement" (consider also with "site:stackoverflow.com" or "site:hubfs.net") seems to provide some good leads.  Briefly, I think the .Net APIs for XML already have good stuff here, so it's just a matter of leveraging them from F#.