# Code-golf: generate pascal's triangle

Tags: algorithm, code-golf, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pascals-triangle

Generate a list of lists (or print, I don't mind) a [Pascal's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) of size N with the least lines of code possible!

Here goes my attempt (118 characters in **python 2.6** using [a trick](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204297/)):

```
c,z,k=locals,[0],'_[1]'
p=lambda n:[len(c()[k])and map(sum,zip(z+c()[k][-1],c()[k][-1]+z))or[1]for _ in range(n)]
```

Explanation:

- the first element of the list comprehension (when the length is 0) is `[1]`
- the next elements are obtained the following way:
- take the previous list and make two lists, one padded with a 0 at the beginning and the other at the end.

  - e.g. for the 2nd step, we take `[1]` and make `[0,1]` and `[1,0]`
- sum the two new lists element by element

  - e.g. we make a new list `[(0,1),(1,0)]` and map with sum.
- repeat n times and that's all.

usage (with pretty printing, actually out of the code-golf xD):

```
result = p(10)
lines = [" ".join(map(str, x)) for x in result]
for i in lines:
    print i.center(max(map(len, lines)))
```

output:

```
             1             
            1 1            
           1 2 1           
          1 3 3 1          
         1 4 6 4 1         
       1 5 10 10 5 1       
      1 6 15 20 15 6 1     
    1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1    
   1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1  
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
```

Comment: why the downvotes? are the code golfs forbidden now?

Comment: I'll vote to reopen if this gets closed.  I like code golf.  I don't understand what's so bad about it.

Comment: maybe it's just me but... if you can't parse an XML file in your language, I ain't upvoting.

Comment: @Triptych I couldn't understand completely your comment, but... are you confusing Pascal the French philosopher and mathematician with Wirth's programming language?

Comment: @fortran, I'm quite familiar with both.  I'm referring to code-golf purpose-built specialty languages like K and J always getting upvoted the most in code golf questions, but you would never use them for anything OTHER than code golf questions.  I'm much more impressed by, say, a 50-char C solution than a 20 char J solution.

Comment: @Triptych sorry, it didn't make much sense to me out of context, I even think I understood the opposite... much clearer now  :-)

Comment: @Triptych: K and J are not code-golf purpose-built languages. plus, J seems to have modules for xml, like http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Addons/xml/sax .

Comment: @Triptych: The financial industry must be doing a lot of code-golfing, then: http://kx.com/Customers/end-user-customers.php

Comment: When ever I see a code golf question what I really want to do is run off and write a DSL and answer "1" using this XXX. That and way over engineer the solution. Full on web service thing with an example of every pattern in the GoF book.
Alas I'm too lazy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[J](http://www.jsoftware.com/)**, another language in the APL family, 9 characters:

```
p=:!/~@i.
```

This uses J's builtin "combinations" verb.

Output:

```
   p 10
1 1 1 1 1  1  1  1  1   1
0 1 2 3 4  5  6  7  8   9
0 0 1 3 6 10 15 21 28  36
0 0 0 1 4 10 20 35 56  84
0 0 0 0 1  5 15 35 70 126
0 0 0 0 0  1  6 21 56 126
0 0 0 0 0  0  1  7 28  84
0 0 0 0 0  0  0  1  8  36
0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  1   9
0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0   1
```

Comment: I wonder how much work it would take to get rid of the 0's. Also, you might want to transpose the result.

Comment: Transposing is easy, just prepend `|:`. In J you'd rather not get rid of the zeroes most of the time, but if you really want to, here's a way to do it: `p=:3 :'(1+i.y) ({.])&.> <"1|: !/~i.y'`

Comment: A shorter way to strip the leading zeros and print it out nicely: `p=:":@(!~i.@>:)"0@i.`

Answer (score 17):

**[K](http://kx.com/Developers/software.php)** ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language))), 15 characters:

```
p:{x{+':x,0}\1}
```

Example output:

```
  p 10
(1
 1 1
 1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
 1 4 6 4 1
 1 5 10 10 5 1
 1 6 15 20 15 6 1
 1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
 1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
 1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
 1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1)
```

It's also easily explained:

```
p:{x {+':x,0} \ 1}
   ^ ^------^ ^ ^
   A    B     C D
```

- `p` is a function taking an implicit parameter `x`.
- `p` unfolds (C) an anonymous function (B) `x` times (A) starting at `1` (D).
- The anonymous function simply takes a list `x`, appends `0` and returns a result by adding (`+`) each adjacent pair (`':`) of values: so e.g. starting with `(1 2 1)`, it'll produce `(1 2 1 0)`, add pairs `(1 1+2 2+1 1+0)`, giving `(1 3 3 1)`.

---

*Update:* Adapted to K4, which shaves off another two characters. For reference, here's the original K3 version:

```
p:{x{+':0,x,0}\1}
```

Comment: Wonderful! I have strong doubts that is going to be anything shorter than this.

Answer (score 14):

**Haskell**, 58 characters:

```
r 0=[1]
r(n+1)=zipWith(+)(0:r n)$r n++[0]
p n=map r[0..n]
```

Output:

```
*Main> p 5
[[1],[1,1],[1,2,1],[1,3,3,1],[1,4,6,4,1],[1,5,10,10,5,1]]
```

More readable:

```
-- # row 0 is just [1]
row 0     = [1]
-- # row (n+1) is calculated from the previous row
row (n+1) = zipWith (+) ([0] ++ row n) (row n ++ [0])
-- # use that for a list of the first n+1 rows
pascal n  = map row [0..n]
```

Comment: Shorter: `r n=take(n+1)$iterate(\a->zipWith(+)(0:a)$a++[0])[1]`

Answer (score 12):

69C in C:

```
f(int*t){int*l=t+*t,*p=t,r=*t,j=0;for(*t=1;l<t+r*r;j=*p++)*l++=j+*p;}
```

Use it like so:

```
int main()
{
#define N 10
    int i, j;
    int t[N*N] = {N};

    f(t);

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            printf("%d ", t[i*N + j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're cheating here! :p the function just computes 1 row, you should include in your character count the code for generating in memory (or printing, whichever is shorter/easier for you) the whole triangle

Comment: Hmm? No it doesn't, the function fills out the left-hand-side of the array that it's passed with the entire triangle.

Answer (score 9):

**[F#](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming): 81 chars**

```
let f=bigint.Factorial
let p x=[for n in 0I..x->[for k in 0I..n->f n/f k/f(n-k)]]
```

Explanation: I'm too lazy to be as clever as the Haskell and K programmers, so I took the straight forward route: each element in Pascal's triangle can be uniquely identified using a row n and col k, where the value of each element is `n!/(k! (n-k)!`.

Answer (score 7):

#### Python: 75 characters

```
def G(n):R=[[1]];exec"R+=[map(sum,zip(R[-1]+[0],[0]+R[-1]))];"*~-n;return R
```

Comment: nice use of single space indentation to save a few characters

Answer (score 4):

Shorter prolog version (112 instead of 164):

```
n([X],[X]).
n([H,I|T],[A|B]):-n([I|T],B),A is H+I.
p(0,[[1]]):-!.
p(N,[R,S|T]):-O is N-1,p(O,[S|T]),n([0|S],R).
```

Answer (score 3):

another stab (python):

```
def pascals_triangle(n):
    x=[[1]]
    for i in range(n-1):
        x.append(list(map(sum,zip([0]+x[-1],x[-1]+[0]))))
    return x
```

Comment: come on, the purpose of a code golf is to make it compact! so rename the function to something like "p" and remove the extra indentation (1 space is enough) and add the character count too :p

Answer (score 2):

Haskell, 164C with formatting:

```
i l=zipWith(+)(0:l)$l++[0]
fp=map (concatMap$(' ':).show)f$iterate i[1]
c n l=if(length l<n)then c n$' ':l++" "else l
cl l=map(c(length$last l))l
pt n=cl$take n fp
```

Without formatting, 52C:

```
i l=zipWith(+)(0:l)$l++[0]
pt n=take n$iterate i[1]
```

A more readable form of it:

```
iterateStep row = zipWith (+) (0:row) (row++[0])
pascalsTriangle n = take n $ iterate iterateStep [1]

-- For the formatted version, we reduce the number of rows at the final step:
formatRow r = concatMap (\l -> ' ':(show l)) r
formattedLines = map formatRow $ iterate iterateStep [1]
centerTo width line =
    if length line < width
        then centerTo width (" " ++ line ++ " ")
        else line
centerLines lines = map (centerTo (length $ last lines)) lines
pascalsTriangle n = centerLines $ take n formattedLines
```

And perl, 111C, no centering:

```
$n=<>;$p=' 1 ';for(1..$n){print"$p\n";$x=" ";while($p=~s/^(?= ?\d)(\d* ?)(\d* ?)/$2/){$x.=($1+$2)." ";}$p=$x;}
```

Comment: Needs `{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}`, which IMO should count into your character totals... ouch.

Comment: Or -fglasgow-exts on the command line... in any case, it can be written with zipWith using only one additional character

Comment: In that case, `zipWith(+)(0:l)$l++[0]` gets you that one character back :)

Answer (score 2):

Scheme — compressed version of 100 characters

```
(define(P h)(define(l i r)(if(> i h)'()(cons r(l(1+ i)(map +(cons 0 r)(append r '(0))))))(l 1 '(1)))
```

This is it in a more readable form (269 characters):

```
(define (pascal height)
  (define (next-row row)
    (map +
         (cons 0 row)
         (append row '(0))))

  (define (iter i row)
    (if (> i height)
        '()
        (cons row
              (iter (1+ i)
                    (next-row row)))))

  (iter 1 '(1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

**VBA/VB6** (392 chars w/ formatting)

```
Public Function PascalsTriangle(ByVal pRows As Integer)

Dim iRow As Integer
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim lValue As Long
Dim sLine As String

  For iRow = 1 To pRows
    sLine = ""
    For iCol = 1 To iRow
      If iCol = 1 Then
        lValue = 1
      Else
        lValue = lValue * (iRow - iCol + 1) / (iCol - 1)
      End If
      sLine = sLine & " " & lValue
    Next
    Debug.Print sLine
  Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

**PHP** 100 characters

```
$v[]=1;while($a<34){echo join(" ",$v)."\n";$a++;for($k=0;$k<=$a;$k++)$t[$k]=$v[$k-1]+$v[$k];$v=$t;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby, 83c:

```
def p(n);n>0?(m=p(n-1);k=m.last;m+[([0]+k).zip(k+[0]).map{|x|x[0]+x[1]}]):[[1]];end
```

test:

```
irb(main):001:0> def p(n);n>0?(m=p(n-1);k=m.last;m+[([0]+k).zip(k+[0]).map{|x|x[0]+x[1]}]):[[1]];end
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> p(5)
=> [[1], [1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 3, 1], [1, 4, 6, 4, 1], [1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]]
irb(main):003:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this C++ version a few years ago:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int,char**a){for(int b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0,g=0,h=0,i=0;b<atoi(a[1]);(d|f|h)>1?e*=d>1?--d:1,g*=f>1?--f:1,i*=h>1?--h:1:((std::cout<<(i*g?e/(i*g):1)<<" "?d=b+=c++==b?c=0,std::cout<<std::endl?1:0:0,h=d-(f=c):0),e=d,g=f,i=h));}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another try, in **prolog** (I'm practising xD), not too short, just 164c:

```
s([],[],[]).
s([H|T],[J|U],[K|V]):-s(T,U,V),K is H+J.
l([1],0).
l(P,N):-M is N-1,l(A,M),append(A,[0],B),s(B,[0|A],P).
p([],-1).
p([H|T],N):-M is N-1,l(H,N),p(T,M).
```

explanation:

- s = sum lists element by element
- l = the Nth row of the triangle
- p = the whole triangle of size N

Answer (score 1):

Another **python** solution, that could be much shorter if the builtin functions had shorter names... **106** characters.

```
from itertools import*
r=range
p=lambda n:[[len(list(combinations(r(i),j)))for j in r(i+1)]for i in r(n)]
```

Answer (score 1):

VBA, 122 chars:

```
Sub p(n)
For r = 1 To n
l = "1"
v = 1
For c = 1 To r - 1
v = v / c * (r - c)
l = l & " " & v
Next
Debug.Print l
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is just a Scala function returning a `List[List[Int]]`. No pretty printing or anything. Any suggested improvements? (I know it's inefficient, but that's not the main challenge now, is it?). 145 C.

```
def p(n: Int)={def h(n:Int):List[Int]=n match{case 1=>1::Nil;case _=>(0::h(n-1) zipAll(h(n-1),0,0)).map{n=>n._1+n._2}};(1 to n).toList.map(h(_))}
```

Or perhaps:

```
def pascal(n: Int) = {
  def helper(n: Int): List[Int] = n match {
    case 1 => 1 :: List()
    case _ => (0 :: helper(n-1) zipAll (helper(n-1),0,0)).map{ n => n._1 + n._2 }
  }
  (1 to n).toList.map(helper(_))
}
```

(I'm a Scala noob, so please be nice to me :D )

Answer (score 0):

a Perl version (139 chars w/o shebang)

```
@p = (1,1);
while ($#p < 20) {
    @q =();
    $z = 0;
    push @p, 0;
    foreach (@p) {
        push @q, $_+$z;
        $z = $_
    }
    @p = @q;
    print "@p\n";
}
```

output starts from 1 2 1

Comment: (btw, you can remove your other answer now :p)

Comment: I will when I figure out how. (I'm new here and still reading the FAQs)

Answer (score 0):

PHP, 115 chars

```
$t[][]=1;
for($i=1;$i<$n;++$i){
$t[$i][0]=1;
for($j=1;$j<$i;++$j)$t[$i][$j]=$t[$i-1][$j-1]+$t[$i-1][$j];
$t[$i][$i]=1;}
```

If you don't care whether print_r() displays the output array in the correct order, you can shave it to 113 chars like

```
$t[][]=1;
for($i=1;$i<$n;++$i){
$t[$i][0]=$t[$i][$i]=1;
for($j=1;$j<$i;++$j)$t[$i][$j]=$t[$i-1][$j-1]+$t[$i-1][$j];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl, 63 characters:

```
for(0..9){push@z,1;say"@z";@z=(1,map{$z[$_-1]+$z[$_]}(1..$#z))}
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt in C++ (378c). Not anywhere near as good as the rest of the posts.. but I'm proud of myself for coming up with a solution on my own =)

```
int* pt(int n)
{
  int s=n*(n+1)/2;
  int* t=new int[s];

  for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    for(int j=0;j<=i;++j)
      t[i*n+j] = (!j || j==i) ? 1 : t[(i-1)*n+(j-1)] + t[(i-1)*n+j];
  return t;
}

int main()
{
  int n,*t;
  std::cin>>n;
  t=pt(n);

  for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
      std::cout<<t[i*n+j]<<' ';
    std::cout<<"\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: the purpose of a code golf is to make short programs xD try at least removing the superfluous whitespace :-p

Comment: I removed most of the whitespace and made other minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I wrote this in response to a challenge on another forum today:

```
def pascals_triangle(n):
    x=[[1]]
    for i in range(n-1):
        x.append([sum(i) for i in zip([0]+x[-1],x[-1]+[0])])
    return x

for x in pascals_triangle(5):
    print('{0:^16}'.format(x))

      [1]       
     [1, 1]     
   [1, 2, 1]    
  [1, 3, 3, 1]  
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Don't forget to add the character count ;-)