# Pascal's triangle

Tags: python

I am looking for a [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) using a Python script.

I have done till here and don’t have any idea how to add on.

```
numstr = raw_input("Please enter the height: ")
height = int()

tri = []

row1 = [1]
row2 = [1, 1]
tri.append(row1)
tri.append(row2)

while len(tri) < height:
```

Comment: While not wanting to take anything away from your efforts, so far, there *was* a Pascal's Triangle Code Golf: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242073/code-golf-generate-pascals-triangle

Answer (score 3):

You would have to take the last row there is in the triangle and create the next one like this:

1. Put a 1 at the start of the new row
2. For every number in the last row except the last, calculate the sum of the number and its right neighbor and put it into the new row
3. Put another 1 at the end of the new row

You could also calculate the new numbers using [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), though that's likely a little more work to get right.

Answer (score 3):

Here's **[the correct way](http://ptri1.tripod.com/)** to make Pascal's triangle.

*[Pascal's Triangle. And Its Patterns](http://ptri1.tripod.com/)*

*[Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)*

[image]

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the next row is crossed axis sum of last row. For example, if the last row is [1, 1], the next row would be:

```
     [1, 1]
+ [1, 1]
-----------
= [1, 2, 1]

     [1, 2, 1]
+ [1, 2, 1]
--------------
= [1, 3, 3, 1]
```

So, the loop body can be like this:

```
tri.append(map(lambda x, y: x + y, [0] + tri[-1], tri[-1] + [0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the [SciPy 'pascal'](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.pascal.html#scipy.linalg.pascal) module:

```
from scipy.linalg import pascal

pascal(6, kind='lower')
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  2,  1,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  3,  3,  1,  0,  0],
   [ 1,  4,  6,  4,  1,  0],
   [ 1,  5, 10, 10,  5,  1]], dtype=uint64)
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to generate a Pascal's triangle:

```
def factorial(x):

    return 1 if x == 0 else x * factorial(x - 1)

def triangle(n):

    return [[factorial(i) / (factorial(j) * factorial(i - j)) for j in range(i + 1)] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is Python code for Pascal's triangle:

```
# Python code for Pascal's triangle
# printPascal() function for printing Pascal's triangle.
def printPascal(N):
    # Declaring two arrays
    arr = [1]
    temp = []

    print("Pascal's triangle of", N, "Rows...")
    # Calculating the next rows.
    for i in range(N):
        # printing current row.
        print("rows", i+1, end=" : ")
        for j in range(len(arr)):
            print(arr[j], end=' ')
        print()

        # Calculating the next rows.
        temp.append(1)
        for j in range(len(arr)-1):
            temp.append(arr[j] + arr[j + 1])
        temp.append(1)

        # Copy the next row to the current row.
        arr = temp
        # Initialize temp to an empty array.
        temp = []


# Driver code
N = 9
printPascal(N)
```

For more details: https://algorithmdotcpp.blogspot.com/2021/07/print-n-rows-of-pascals-triangle-in-cpp-and-python.html

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (the blog post was removed).

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```cpp
// C++ code for Pascal's triangle
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long unsigned int Factorial(long unsigned int Number)
{
    long unsigned int Fact = 0;
    if (Number == 0)
        return (long unsigned int) 1;
    else
    {
       Fact = Number*Factorial(Number-1);
       return Fact;
    }
}

long unsigned int Combination(long unsigned int num1, long unsigned int num2)
{
    long unsigned int Comb, num3;
    long unsigned int Factor1, Factor2, Factor3;
    Factor1 = Factorial(num1);
    Factor2 = Factorial(num2);
    num3 = num1 - num2;
    Factor3 = Factorial(num3);
    Comb = Factor1/(Factor2*Factor3);

    return(Comb);
}

int main()
{
    long unsigned int i, j, Num=0;
    long unsigned int **Matrix;
    clrscr();
    printf(" %d\n ", sizeof(long unsigned int));
    printf("Enter index of square matrix num: ");
    scanf("%lu", &Num);

    Matrix = (long unsigned int **) malloc(Num*Num*sizeof(long unsigned int *));

    for(i=0; i<Num; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<Num; j++)
        {
            *(*(Matrix+i)+j) = 0;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<Num; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            printf(" %lu ", *(*(Matrix + i) + j));
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<Num; i=i+1)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=i; j=j+1)
        {
            *(*(Matrix + i) + j) = Combination(i, j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(i=0; i<Num; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=i; j++)
        {
            //printf(" \n %lu  %lu \n", i, j);
            printf("  %lu  ", *(*(Matrix + i) + j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

C# solution:

```csharp
public IList<IList<int>> Generate(int numRows) {
    var result = new List<IList<int>>();
        var item1 = new List<int>();
        item1.Add(1);
        result.Add(item1);

        if (numRows == 1)
            return result;

        var item2 = new List<int>();
        item2.Add(1);
        item2.Add(1);
        result.Add(item2);

        if (numRows == 2)
            return result;

        var i = 2;
        while (i != numRows)
        {
            var data = result.Last().ToArray();
            var n = data.Length;
            var item = new int[n + 1];
            item[0] = 1;
            item[n] = 1;
            for (var x = 1; x < n; x++)
                item[x] = data[x - 1] + data[x];
            result.Add(item);
            i++;
        }

    return result;
}
```