# F#: More return points in functions, how to handle them?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, return, unit-type

I have a problem when returning values in complex functions. Examples are always better:

Consider the following function:

```
let myf (mypar: int) =
   mypar + 1
```

Well no probel here, this function is compiled correctly and the signature is:

```
val myf: int -> int
```

OK, well. Now consider this code:

```
let myf (mypar: int) =
   if mypar = 2 then
      4 (* ERROR *)
   mypar + 1
```

This does not work:

This expression was expected to have type unit but here has int

This error is raised everytime I try to return from my function when I am inside a `if`, a `while` a `for` or every other block. I thought that the problem was assuring that all possible return paths return the same type, but here I do not understand what happens.

Please note that if I insert a `()` unit everything works for example:

```
let myf (mypar: int) =
   if mypar = 2 then
      () (* No error *)
   mypar + 1
```

But that unit does not make my function return!!! it continues!!!
Furthermore, could you please explain me how F# handles this???

Thankyou

Comment: Related post - [Multiple Exits From F# Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1609851/465053)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To add some more details, the problem with your approach is that everything in F# is an *expression*. This makes it a lot easier to reason about your programs (because you don't need to keep track of the *currently executing statement*), but it means that you always have to write a complete expression.

If you try to write something like `return`, it would be as if you wrote the following in C# (This probably explains why F# doesn't allow this kind of things):

```
int a = 10 + (3 * (return 10; 2));
return a;
```

Why didn't you get error when you wrote `if .. then ()`? The `()` expression creates a value of type `unit` that is special, because it has only one valid value. F# allows you to write `if .. then` without `else` when returning `unit`, because it can figure out that the `else` branch has to return the only existing unit value, so it sees your code as:

```
if something then ()
else () // implicitly added by the compiler
```

The only difference is throwing an exception (using `raise`) which behaves just like in C#. You could break out of a function using exception, but it is much better idea to rewrite the code to have a complete valid expression.

Answer (score 10):

F# has no return statement. The only way to do what you want to here, to choose either one block or the other, is with `if` .. `else`:

```
let myf (mypar: int) =
   if mypar = 2 then
      4
   else
      mypar + 1
```

Alternatively, throwing an exception exits the function early:

```
let myf (mypar: int) =
   if mypar = 2 then
      failwith "invalid argument"

   mypar + 1
```

Comment: yes it works but my problem, generally speaking is that also in nested while or other if I cannot return... Should I use workflows?????

Comment: No. You should instead write your loop as a recursive function.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using an `else` instead?

```
let myf (mypar: int) =
   if mypar = 2 then
      4
   else
      mypar + 1
```

I haven't tried it myself, but it's worth a shot :)

(Also consider using pattern matching instead, of course.)

Comment: What's Package matching? You mean pattern matching?

Comment: @nyinyithann: Absolutely - that's what I get for posting just as I'm leaving work :)