# why there is no return statement in Elixir

Tags: elixir

To make the question short, what is the reason why there is no `return` statement in Elixir and some (most ? all ?) functional languages ?

To make it a bit longer, I'm facing a situation where in Java, Groovy, C, Ruby ... I would write some thing like

```
def func (some, parameters) {

  # say some error
  if(condition 1) {
    return -1
  }

  # execute some function and return from here the result
  if(condition 2) {
    return process1(params)
  }

  # execute 'default' behavior when no condition matches and return result
  process2(params)
}
```

Of course, this can be written as nested `if`s but if the list of conditions is long, the code just gets unreadable.

I read the answers for the question *[Return statement in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239919/return-statement-in-elixir)* : they explain clearly how to implement this kind of pattern but not the reason of not having `return`.

I believe having `return` would break some FP concept but I wonder which ones and why.

Comment: FYI You can use `cond` instead of nested `if` in Elixir. With `cond` you won't have more than 1 extra level of indentation compared to the code you've written (that too for the last group of statements only).

Comment: Or you can use `with` which can be very useful in some situations and makes code readable and nice. But I am also interested why there is no built in return statement.

Comment: You're asking a pretty broad question.  There's discussion of this here: http://wiki.c2.com/?SingleFunctionExitPoint among other places.  I am inclined to say this should either be closed or moved to Programmer's Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there are other ways to do that same thing that is more like Elixir.

Multiple function heads do basically the same thing as what you're doing:

```
defp merge_sweep(a, [], _) when is_list(a), do: a
defp merge_sweep([], b, _) when is_list(b), do: b
defp merge_sweep([a|as], [b|bs], cmp) do
  if cmp.(a, b) do
    [a|merge_sweep(as, [b|bs], cmp)]
  else
    [b|merge_sweep([a|as], bs, cmp)]
  end
end
```

And since functions in functional programming don't have any side-effects (ignoring `:ets` for now), why should you have to write `return` everywhere? You always want to return something in every branch, so you might as well just always return the last expression in each branch.

I asked for Golang's `defer` statement in Elixir when I started, because I came from Go. It's simply that each language has a different way of doing things.
Writing C-like code in Python just looks weird and foreign.

---

The real answer is probably "because Erlang doesn't".

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is because Erlang doesn't have early returns.

The longer answer is because early returns are an anti-pattern and they make your code harder to read and reason about. It doesn't have anything to do with functional programming other than it being a common feature of "functional" programming languages. There is no program you can write with early returns that you can't without them.

Comment: This answer seems dogmatic to me. Opinions on readability will vary, but the original question was seeking to avoid the nested `if` to be more readable. Guard clauses are more idiomatic and I think more readable. (Filip's answer is closer to the mark for me.)

Comment: @cleaver programming languages are very dogmatic