# Time complexity of Merge Sort in python

Tags: python

I implemented merge-sort in python

```
import sys

def mergeSort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array

    middle = len(array) / 2
    left   = mergeSort(array[:middle])
    right  = mergeSort(array[middle:])
    return merge(left, right)

def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    while left and right:
        if left[0] < right[0]: result.append(left.pop(0))
        else: result.append(right.pop(0))

    while left: result.append(left.pop(0))
    while right: result.append(right.pop(0))

    return result

array = map(int, sys.stdin)
print mergeSort(array)
```

But someone told me that the time complexity of list.pop(0) in python is linear or O(n). In that case the above code won't sort in O(n log n). What changes should I make to it?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063697/why-is-my-mergesort-so-slow-in-python . Specifically the community wiki/huitseeker answer. It has lots of sorts:  https://gist.github.com/1146063

Answer (score 3):

The someone who told you that is correct. `list.pop()` is O(1), but `list.pop(0)` is linear, because the whole list has to be shifted to fill in the space. Thus in general, `list.pop(x)` is O(n - x). As [Ignacio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9621810/577088) suggests, you could use a [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) -- popping from a deque is O(1) on either side. (But slows to O(n) in the middle.)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a collections.deque, but you still won't beat Timsort.

Comment: My aim is not to beat Timsort here.