# Tail-recursive Implementation of Scala's List partition method

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

For exercise purposes I've been trying to implement a couple of Scala's List methods in a functional manner, one of them being `partition`. Assume the following signature:

```
def partition[T](l: List[T], f: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T])
```

It returns a tuple consisting of two lists - the first one contains all the elements from `l` that fulfill the passed predicate `f` and another one which contains all the other elements.

I came up with the following recursive solution which is unfortunately not tail-recursive:

```
  def partition[T](l: List[T], f: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T]) = {
    l match {
      case Nil => (Nil, Nil)
      case head :: rest => {
        val (left, right) = partition(rest, f)
        if (f(head))
          (head :: left, right)
        else
          (left, head :: right)
      }
    }
  }
```

In this stack overflow question ([Can all recursive functions be re-written as tail-recursions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715224/can-all-recursive-functions-be-re-written-as-tail-recursions)) it is made clear that an accumulator could be used in some cases. In the given one I would claim that this is not possible since it would return the final lists in a reversed manner.

Could you please give me a tail-recursive solution? Maybe even with continuation passing (I haven't really understood how it works and how it could be applied)?

Comment: You can reverse the results before returning them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a tuple as the accumulator, and make sure to reverse the lists before returning them:

```
def partition[T](l: List[T])(f: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T]) = {
  @tailrec
  def partitionInternal(l: List[T])(acc: (List[T], List[T])): (List[T], List[T]) = {
    l match {
      case Nil => acc
      case head :: tail =>
        if (f(head)) partitionInternal(tail)(head :: acc._1, acc._2)
        else partitionInternal(tail)(acc._1, head :: acc._2)
    }
  }

  val (lf, r) = partitionInternal(l)((List.empty[T], List.empty[T]))
  (lf.reverse, r.reverse)
}
```

An alternative solution would be to append (`:+`) instead of prepending (`::`), but then you pay the price of O(n) for every entry.

Another idea would be to use a `ListBuffer[T]` instead of `List[T]` for the internal recursive implementation which has constant time append. All you need to do is call `.toList` at the end:

```
def partition[T](l: List[T])(f: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T]) = {
  @tailrec
  def partitionInternal(l: List[T])(acc: (ListBuffer[T], ListBuffer[T])): (ListBuffer[T], ListBuffer[T])  = {
    l match {
      case Nil => acc
      case head :: tail =>
        val (leftAcc, rightAcc) = acc
        if (f(head)) partitionInternal(tail)((leftAcc += head, rightAcc))
        else partitionInternal(tail)((leftAcc, rightAcc += head))
    }
  }

  val (lf, r) = partitionInternal(l)((ListBuffer.empty[T], ListBuffer.empty[T]))
  (lf.toList, r.toList)
}
```

Additionaly, notice that I create a separate argument list for the `List[T]` and the function from `T => Boolean`. That is in order to help the compiler infer the right type argument when applying the method since type inference flows between parameter lists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep two accumulators, one for `left` and one for `right`. When you're done going through the input list, simply return both accumulators (reversing them to get back to the original order):

```
def partition[T](l: List[T], f: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T]) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def aux(tl: List[T], left: List[T], right: List[T]): (List[T], List[T]) = tl match {
    case Nil => (left.reverse, right.reverse)
    case head :: rest => {
      if (f(head))
        aux(rest, head :: left, right)
      else
        aux(rest, left, head :: right)
    }
  }

  aux(l, List(), List())
}
```

---

Using it:

```
scala> def partition[T](l: List[T], f: T => Boolean): (List[T], List[T]) = {
     |   @annotation.tailrec
     |   def aux(tl: List[T], left: List[T], right: List[T]): (List[T], List[T]) = tl match {
     |     case Nil => (left.reverse, right.reverse)
     |     case head :: rest => {
     |       if (f(head))
     |         aux(rest, head :: left, right)
     |       else
     |         aux(rest, left, head :: right)
     |     }
     |   }
     | 
     |   aux(l, List(), List())
     | } 
partition: [T](l: List[T], f: T => Boolean)(List[T], List[T])

scala> partition(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (i: Int) => i%2 == 0)
res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(2, 4),List(1, 3, 5))
```