# F# tree-building function causes stack overflow in Xamarin Studio

Tags: recursion, xamarin, f#, functional-programming, stack-overflow

I'm trying to build up some rules in a tree structure, with logic gates i.e. *and*, *not*, *or* as well as conditions, e.g. property *x* equals value *y*. I wrote the most obvious recursive function first, which worked. I then tried to write a version that wouldn't cause a stack-overflow in continuation passing style taking my cue from [this post about generic tree folding](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/catamorphisms-part-two/) and [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888702/are-there-problems-that-cannot-be-written-using-tail-recursion).

It works for small trees (depth of approximately 1000), but unfortunately when using a large tree it causes a stackoverflow when I run it on my Mac with Xamarin Studio. Can anyone tell me whether I've misunderstood how F# treats tail-recursive code or whether this code isn't tail-recursive?

[The full sample is here](https://gist.github.com/NickLydon/fb828bb17349226d835b5778be8f0b06).

```
let FoldTree andF orF notF leafV t data = 
    let rec Loop t cont = 
        match t with
        | AndGate (left, right)->
            Loop left  (fun lacc ->  
            Loop right (fun racc -> 
            cont (andF lacc racc))) 
        | OrGate (left, right)->
            Loop left  (fun lacc ->  
            Loop right (fun racc -> 
            cont (orF lacc racc))) 
        | NotGate exp ->
            Loop exp (fun acc -> cont (notF acc))
        | EqualsExpression(property,value) -> cont (leafV (property,value))
    Loop t id

let evaluateContinuationPassingStyle tree data = 
    FoldTree (&&) (||) (not) (fun (prop,value) -> data |> Map.find prop |> ((=) value)) tree data
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code is tail-recursive, you got it right. But the problem is with Mono. See, Mono is not as high-quality implementation of .NET as the official thing. In particular, it doesn't do tail call elimination. Like, at all.

For the simplest (and most prevalent) case of self-recursion this doesn't matter too much, because the compiler catches it earlier. The F# compiler is smart enough to spot that the function is calling itself, figure out under what conditions, and convert it into a neat `while` loop, so that the compiled code doesn't make any calls at all.

But when your tail call is to a function passed as parameter, the compiler can't do that, because the actual function being called isn't known until runtime. In fact, even mutual recursion of two functions can't be converted into a loop reliably.

Possible solutions:

- Switch to .NET Core.
- Don't use recursive continuations, use accumulator instead (might not be possible).
- Use self-recursion and pass manually maintained stack of continuations.
- If all else fails, use a mutable stack.

Comment: That's disappointing. Spent quite a while thinking it was my implementation that was the issue. Found this [bug report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12635#c11), which looks like it matches this and the final comment makes it look like it won't be resolved soon.

Comment: Mono is going away. Switch to .NET Core.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I don't think Mono is going away anytime soon for Xamarin.