# How To Apply a Function to an Array of float Arrays?

Tags: f#

Let's suppose I have n arrays, where n is a variable (some number greater than 2, usually less than 10).

Each array has k elements.

I also have an array of length n that contains a set of weights that dictate how I would like to linearly combine all the arrays.

I am trying to create a high performance higher order function to combine these arrays in F#.

How can I do this, so that I get a function that takes an array of arrays (arrs is a sample), a weights array (weights), and then computed a weighted sum based on the weights?

```
let weights = [|.6;;.3;.1|]

let arrs = [| [|.0453;.065345;.07566;1.562;356.6|] ; 
              [|.0873;.075565;.07666;1.562222;3.66|] ; 
              [|.06753;.075675;.04566;1.452;3.4556|] |]
```

thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Can you give an example output? It's not clear to me if you want just one number at the end, or an array of k with the sum of the n elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
let combine weights arrs =
  Array.map2 (fun w -> Array.map ((*) w)) weights arrs 
  |> Array.reduce (Array.map2 (+))
```

**EDIT**

Here's some (much needed) explanation of how this works.  Logically, we want to do the following:

1. Apply each weight to its corresponding row.
2. Add together the weight-adjusted rows.

The two lines above do just that.

1. We use the `Array.map2` function to combine corresponding weights and rows; the way that we combine them is to multiply each element in the row by the weight, which is accomplished via the inner `Array.map`.
2. Now we have an array of weighted rows and need to add them together.  We can do this one step at a time by keeping a running sum, adding each array in turn.  The way we sum two arrays pointwise is to use `Array.map2` again, using `(+)` as the function for combining the elements from each.  We wrap this in an `Array.reduce` to apply this addition function to each row in turn, starting with the first row.

Hopefully this is a reasonably elegant approach to the problem, though the point-free style admittedly makes it a bit tricky to follow.  However, note that it's not especially performant; doing in-place updates rather than creating new arrays with each application of `map`, `map2`, and `reduce` would be more efficient.  Unfortunately, the standard library doesn't contain nice analogues of these operations which work in-place.  It would be relatively easy to create such analogues, though, and they could be used in almost exactly the same way as I've done here.

Comment: @David - thanks.  There are so many useful combinators in the standard library that it's often just a question of how to combine them to get what you want.

Comment: @kvb, That could do with some explanation. It took me a while to work out where the second argument for the first map2 function went. It should be 'T1 -> 'T2 -> 'U, but I only see w. If I have understood correctly, partial application of the map2 function to weights yields another function to be applied to arrs? (Brain explodes)

Comment: Added to my list of handy F# snippets. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833180/handy-f-snippets/2332111#2332111 This solution blows me away because 1) it's so elegant, and 2) I'd never have found it.

Comment: @Benjol - yes, it desperately needed explanation, which I've added above.  I'm glad that you found it elegant; thanks for the kind words.

Comment: It could also be written like: 
"let combine w = Array.map2 ((*) >> Array.map) w >> Array.reduce (Array.map2 (+))" 
though your solution is easier to understand or explain.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this did it for me:

```
let weights = [|0.6;0.3;0.1|]

let arrs = [| [|0.0453;0.065345;0.07566;1.562;356.6|] ; 
              [|0.0873;0.075565;0.07666;1.562222;3.66|] ; 
              [|0.06753;0.075675;0.04566;1.452;3.4556|] |]

let applyWeight x y = x * y

let rotate (arr:'a[][]) = 
    Array.map (fun y -> (Array.map (fun x -> arr.[x].[y])) [|0..arr.Length - 1|]) [|0..arr.[0].Length - 1|]

let weightedarray = Array.map (fun x -> Array.map(applyWeight (fst x)) (snd x)) (Array.zip weights arrs)

let newarrs = Array.map Array.sum (rotate weightedarray)

printfn "%A" newarrs
```

By the way.. the 0 preceding a float value is necessary.