# how to get pairs of consecutive values from F# Seq

Tags: f#, sequence

I have a sequence with `{"1";"a";"2";"b";"3";"c";...}`.

How can I transform this seq into `{("1","a");("2","b");("3","c");...}`

Comment: Here's a related answer which might interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833180/handy-f-snippets/2271132#2271132, though it's for lists, not Seq.

Answer (score 21):

Here is a much-too-clever solution:

```
let s = ["1";"a";"2";"b";"3";"c"]

let pairs s =
    s |> Seq.pairwise 
      |> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> i%2=0, x) 
      |> Seq.filter fst 
      |> Seq.map snd

printfn "%A" (pairs s)
```

Answer (score 12):

Enumerators are not always evil.

```
let pairs (source: seq<_>) =
    seq { 
        use iter = source.GetEnumerator() 
        while iter.MoveNext() do
            let first = iter.Current
            if iter.MoveNext() then
                let second = iter.Current 
                yield (first, second)
    }
```

Here is the F# source code of `Seq.pairwise` taken from `FSharp.Core/seq.fs`

```
[<CompiledName("Pairwise")>]
let pairwise (source: seq<'T>) = //'
    checkNonNull "source" source
    seq { use ie = source.GetEnumerator() 
          if ie.MoveNext() then
              let iref = ref ie.Current
              while ie.MoveNext() do
                  let j = ie.Current 
                  yield (!iref, j)
                  iref := j }
```

Comment: "Enumerators are not always evil" +1 to that.

Answer (score 8):

Since F# 4.0, you can now use chunkBySize

```
let source = seq ["1";"a";"2";"b";"3";"c"]

let pairs source =
    source
    |> Seq.chunkBySize 2
    |> Seq.map (fun a -> a.[0], a.[1])

;;
printfn "%A" (pairs source)
```

Comment: This does the trick for me! But we should consider to use the Seq.tryItem to retrieve the indexed values. It could throw an exception if the source list has an odd number of values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a variation on @Brian's solution:

```
["1";"a";"2";"b";"3";"c";"4";"d";"5";"e";"6";"f"]
|> Seq.pairwise
|> Seq.mapi (fun i x -> if i%2=0 then Some(x) else None)
|> Seq.choose id
```

And here's a brain-melter using Seq.scan:

```
["1";"a";"2";"b";"3";"c";"4";"d";"5";"e";"6";"f"]
|> Seq.scan (fun ((i,prev),_) n -> match prev with
                                   | Some(n') when i%2=0 -> ((i+1,Some(n)), Some(n',n))
                                   | _ -> ((i+1,Some(n)), None))
            ((-1,None), None)
|> Seq.choose snd
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using LazyLists for this.

```
let (|Cons|Nil|) = LazyList.(|Cons|Nil|)

let paired items =
    let step = function
        | Cons(x, Cons(y, rest)) ->
            Some((x, y), rest)
        | _ ->
            None
    Seq.unfold step (LazyList.ofSeq items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching in the following way:

```
let list = ["1";"2";"3";"4";"5";"6"]

let rec convert l =
    match l with
        x :: y :: z -> (x,y) :: convert z
        | x :: z -> (x,x) :: convert z
        | [] -> []

let _ = 
  convert list
```

but you have to decide what to do if the list has an odd number of elements (in my solution a pair with same value is produced)

Comment: (I don't know if there are clever constructs in F#, I'm used to OCaml :)

Comment: this would work if it was a list but i have a very large seq. not sure if this pattern matching approach will work on a Seq

Comment: why shouldn't it work? It goes through the list an build the new one by concatenating. It should be linear complexity.. or you are worried about stack overflow?

Comment: oh you mean that you want to keep it lazy?

Comment: @functional: here's the same code, but uses continuation passing to make it tail-recursive http://pastebin.com/VTkqgi8k