# Getting every nth Element of a Sequence

Tags: f#

I am looking for a way to create a sequence consisting of every nth element of another sequence, but don't seem to find a way to do that in an elegant way. I can of course hack something, but I wonder if there is a library function that I'm not seeing.

The sequence functions whose names end in -i seem to be quite good for the purpose of figuring out when an element is the nth one or (multiple of n)th one, but I can only see `iteri` and `mapi`, none of which really lends itself to the task.

Example:

```
let someseq = [1;2;3;4;5;6]
let partial = Seq.magicfunction 3 someseq
```

Then `partial` should be `[3;6]`. Is there anything like it out there?

*Edit:*

If I am not quite as ambitious and allow for the `n` to be constant/known, then I've just found that the following should work:

```
let rec thirds lst =
    match lst with
    | _::_::x::t -> x::thirds t // corrected after Tomas' comment
    | _ -> []
```

Would there be a way to write this shorter?

Comment: You could use `mapi` to turn each element of the list into a `Some` or a `None`, `filter` out the `None`s, and then `map` them back to the undecorated type again.

Comment: Your solution using lists looks good (but you probably wanted to write `_::_::x::t` (instead of `(_, _, x)::t` which uses list of tuples). The difference is that `Seq` will work with other collections than lists, but that may not be a problem for you. Your version with lists is a nice functional code.

Comment: Yes, of course, it must be `_::_::x::t`, should have asked the compiler before pasting it in here.

Comment: Still wondering what the optimally efficient solution would be for the general case, but for my problem at hand I am going with the pattern matching now. Thanks for taking the time to answer this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the behavior by composing `mapi` with other functions:

```
let everyNth n seq = 
  seq |> Seq.mapi (fun i el -> el, i)              // Add index to element
      |> Seq.filter (fun (el, i) -> i % n = n - 1) // Take every nth element
      |> Seq.map fst                               // Drop index from the result
```

The solution using options and `choose` as suggested by Annon would use only two functions, but the body of the first one would be slightly more complicated (but the principle is essentially the same).

A more efficient version using the `IEnumerator` object directly isn't too difficult to write:

```
let everyNth n (input:seq<_>) = 
  seq { use en = input.GetEnumerator()
        // Call MoveNext at most 'n' times (or return false earlier)
        let rec nextN n = 
          if n = 0 then true
          else en.MoveNext() && (nextN (n - 1)) 
        // While we can move n elements forward...
        while nextN n do
          // Retrun each nth element
          yield en.Current }
```

EDIT: The snippet is also available here: http://fssnip.net/1R

Comment: Don't know who was faster, you or 'Anon.', but it's both the same suggestion, isn't it? It doesn't look horribly efficient, though, does it?

Comment: It isn't horribly efficient (there are some additional function calls and indirections, because it uses 3 iterators under the cover), but it may not be too bad (there are no intermediate lists that would have to be allocated). For a more efficient version, you'll either need mutation (in sequence expression) or use the underlying `IEnumerator`

Answer (score 10):

`Seq.choose` works nicely in these situations because it allows you do the `filter` work within the `mapi` lambda.

```
let everyNth n elements =
    elements
    |> Seq.mapi (fun i e -> if i % n = n - 1 then Some(e) else None)
    |> Seq.choose id
```

Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126351/how-to-get-pairs-of-consecutive-values-from-f-seq/4129785#4129785).