# Different argument order for getting N-th element of Array, List or Seq

Tags: f#, pipeline

Is there a good reason for a different argument order in functions getting N-th element of Array, List or Seq:

```
Array.get source index
List .nth source index
Seq  .nth index  source
```

I would like to use pipe operator and it seems possible only with Seq:

```
s |> Seq.nth n
```

Is there a way to have the same notation with Array or List?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think of any good reason to define `Array.get` and `List.nth` this way. Given that pipeplining is very common in F#, they should have been defined so that the `source` argument came last.

In case of `List.nth`, it doesn't change much because you can use `Seq.nth` and time complexity is still `O(n)` where `n` is length of the list:

```
[1..100] |> Seq.nth 10
```

It's not a good idea to use `Seq.nth` on arrays because you lose random access. To keep `O(1)` running time of `Array.get`, you can define:

```
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Array =
    /// Get n-th element of an array in O(1) running time
    let inline nth index source = Array.get source index
```

In general, different argument order can be alleviated by using `flip` function:

```
let inline flip f x y = f y x
```

You can use it directly on the functions above:

```
[1..100] |> flip List.nth 10
[|1..100|] |> flip Array.get 10
```

Answer (score 7):

Just use backward pipe operator:

```
[1..1000] |> List.nth <| 42
```

Since both operators are left associative, `x |> f <| y` is parsed as `(x |> f) <| y`, and this does the trick.

Backward pipe operator is also useful if you want to remove parentheses: `f (very long expression)` can be replaced with `f <| very long expression`.

Comment: It does the trick, but I don't like its readability - very claustrophobic!

Comment: @PaulJurczak Absolutely, it's rather a matter of style. Personally, I love operators, but they naturally have [limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12499093/974789) in F#, so it's a choice between `flip`, extension methods, and `<|`. It seems there's no better idea.

Comment: +1 `not` and `defaultArg` made me accustomed to using `<|`; it doesn't seem so awkward once you get used to it.

Answer (score 5):

Since Pad and bytebuster answered your last question I will focus on the why part.

This is based my current knowledge and not historical facts.

Since F# derived from OCaml and OCaml has [Array](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Array.html) and [List](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html) but [not Seq](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/index.html) and F# uses |> for natural pipelining and [type checking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13821811/1243762) and [OCaml lacks the pipleline operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410953/converting-f-pipeline-operators-to-ocaml), the authors of F# made the switch for Seq. But obviously to be backward compatablie with OCaml they did not switch everything.

Comment: OCaml heritage theory makes a lot of sense.