# Why does Seq and List have different signature for nth?

Tags: f#, method-signature

I noticed that the signature of `nth` of `Seq` differs from that of `List` in the placement of the index (`int`).

- [`Seq.nth : int -> seq<'T> -> 'T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340265.aspx)
- [`List.nth : 'T list -> int -> 'T`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370354%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I've just noticed it after I tried the following:

```
[1..10] |> List.nth 2      // error
2 |> List.nth [1..10]      // working, but looks awkward for me
List.nth [1..10] 2         // I suspect this is the expected use 
seq { 1..10 } |> Seq.nth 2 // working
```

I'm aware that it's not possible to determine initially the number of items in `Seq` because it's computed lazily unlike that of `List`, I just don't see how their difference will affect the signature of `List.nth`.

Comment: and here is one more, with some possible answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184949/different-argument-order-for-getting-n-th-element-of-array-list-or-seq (Honestly, I have no idea - it looks pretty silly!)

Comment: @TomasPetricek thanks for the comments. The question is indeed a duplicate.