# FSharp order of function parameters

Tags: f#, functional-programming

Since functions in FSharp with multiple parameters get curried inherently into functions with only one parameter, should the signature of `Seq.filter` have to be

```
Seq.filter predicate source
```

?
How different will it be from

```
Seq.filter source predicate
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this should be a separate question. From a performance perspective, is the first better than the second?

Comment: I think you are implying the use of flip with the second. You don't have to use flip with the second you just can't write it more succinctly.

Comment: yup. I get it. Thanks..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first order (predicate, sequence) is more appropriate for chaining sequence combinators via the `|>` operator. Typically, you have a single sequence to which you apply a number of operations/transformations, consider something like

```
xs |> Seq.map ... |> Seq.filter ... |> Seq. ...
```

etc. Reversing the order of the parameters to (source, predicate) would prohibit that (or at least make it much more awkward to express). That (and maybe also partial application) is why for (almost) all the default `Seq` combinators the last parameter is the sequence the operation is applied to.

Answer (score 6):

The reason it is

```
Seq.filter predicate source
```

instead of

```
Seq.filter soure predicate
```

is so that you can do this

```
source
|> Seq.filter predicate
```

Since you are more likely to build a new function using `Seq.filter predicate`

```
let isEven = Seq.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
```

you can now do

```
source |> isEven
```

There are functions in F# where the order of parameters are not done like this because of it's history of coming from OCaml. See: [Different argument order for getting N-th element of Array, List or Seq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15184949/1243762)

Answer (score 5):

Yes `Seq.filter` takes the predicate followed by the sequence to filter. If you want to provide them in the other order you could write a function to reverse the arguments:

```
let flip f a b = f b a
```

then you could write

```
(flip Seq.filter) [1..10] (fun i -> i > 3)
```

The existing order is more convenient however since it makes partial application more useful e.g.

```
 [1..3] |> Seq.map ((*)2) |> Seq.filter (fun i -> i > 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

and you have also ||> for piping functions accepting two arguments signature, or partially apply 2 arguments to a wider signature. : )